# Pushing to Heroku doesn't install ally my gems and gives me an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, bundler, gemfile

I get an error from Heroku basically saying `devise` wasn't installed. My Gemfile is pretty straightforward so I'm not sure why this is happening.

**Terminal Error Message:**

```
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
remote:        Bundle completed (165.20s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: uninitialized constant Devise
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_a402138a4194014f95671512ec440379/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to damp-garden-9562.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/damp-garden-9562.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/damp-garden-9562.git'
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'spring'
gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'mailcatcher'
gem 'rails_12factor'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

ruby "2.2.2p95"
```

**EDIT:**
**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (5.2.0.1)
      execjs
      json
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.5)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.0.0.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.19)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (5.0.0)
      columnize (= 0.9.0)
    capistrano (3.4.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-passenger (0.1.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.3)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    colorize (0.7.7)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    daemons (1.2.2)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.5.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.5)
    execjs (2.5.2)
    globalid (0.3.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    loofah (2.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mailcatcher (0.6.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0.0, <= 1.0.5)
      mail (~> 2.3)
      sinatra (~> 1.2)
      skinny (~> 0.2.3)
      sqlite3 (~> 1.3)
      thin (~> 1.5.0)
    mime-types (2.6.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.7.0)
    multi_json (1.11.1)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.9.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.18.2)
    rack (1.6.2)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    responders (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5)
    sass (3.4.14)
    sass-rails (5.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sinatra (1.4.6)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    skinny (0.2.3)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0.0)
      thin (~> 1.5.0)
    spring (1.3.6)
    sprockets (3.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10)
    sshkit (1.7.1)
      colorize (>= 0.7.0)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.1.3)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  autoprefixer-rails
  bootstrap-sass
  byebug
  capistrano
  capistrano-passenger
  capistrano-rails
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  mailcatcher
  pg
  rails (= 4.2.1)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.3
```

Why isn't bundle installing all my gems?

Comment: can you post your gemfile.lock?